# How to add multiple websites on a single IP address?

Tags: domains, apache, ip-address, vps

I have a VDS server and a dedicated IP address. The question is how to add multiple sites in a single domain?
For example I have 3 sites as below:

- `www.company.co`
- `www.webdesign.com`
- `www.inet.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good tutorial on hosting multiple websites with apache2, note the use of a2ensite command over creating symlinks

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412

Comment: very informative tut, tnx.

Answer (score 6):

In 000-default (usually in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default)

You can use the VirtualHost tag to separate different sites.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1
    ServerName www1.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2
    ServerName www2.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```